# AngularJS Obfuscation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, obfuscation

I am trying to obfuscate my angularjs app and it is breaking. I am aware that this is an issue with the framework and they have tried to remedy it via the $inject method.

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 See the "Note on Minification" section.

To resolve this they recommend doing `YourController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];`

I went ahead and did that to match my application like so:

```
AventosController.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$q','controllerComm'];
VforumController.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$timeout','controllerComm'];
```

Well, it still isn't working. The error I receive in the console is:

`Error: Unknown provider: cProvider <- c <- controllerComm`

Anyway to remedy this?

**EDIT**

controllerComm

```
app.factory('controllerComm', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
  var showVforum    = {};
  showVforum.result = false;
  showVforum.prepBroadcast = function(val)
  {
    this.result = val;
    this.broadcastVal();
  }

  showVforum.broadcastVal = function()
  {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('toggleVforum')
  }
  return showVforum;
}]);
```

**EDIT 2** not working after obfuscation

```
$scope.launchVforum = function()
{
  $scope.installationVideo = ($scope.installationVideo) ? false : true;
  controllerComm.prepBroadcast($scope.installationVideo);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try injecting at the controller definition.

```
app.controller('myCtrlr', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'controllerComm', function ($scope, $http, $q, controllerComm) {
    ...
}]); // end myCtrlr
```

Also is "controllerComm" defined?

Comment: So rather than defining a controller like: `function AventosController (..){..}` I should define it via `app.controller('AventosController',[...]` ? I have it defined the first way right now

Comment: and yes controllerComm is defined. I'll update my post with it

Comment: Ahh, I got it. I did what you said, setup the controllers in that format but was still getting the error. I did the same to my `controllerComm` and that fixed it! Thanks a ton

Comment: Yes I would define my controllers that way, whether or not it fixes your problem during minification I'm not sure; but it helps to keep it all together for readability and understanding of what is going on.  Also I usually create separate modules for my controllers, filters, directives and services then inject them into the main application module.

Comment: @Ronnie, welcome, glad I could set you on a path to solving your problem.

Comment: I only have one thing not working so far. I updated my code as edit 2 with the block not working. I think it may have to do with `controllerComm`?

Comment: Yep, I am doing a log and when I `console.log(controllerComm.result)` it is undefined. Works fine unminified

Comment: I appologize, it doesn't work unminified either. I thought it did. This must be another issue since I changed my `controllerComm` definition. Thanks again

Comment: Saw your other post and posted a possible solution to that.